# How to share adapter items with two recycler views?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement `Instagram` like `Search fragment` where they have explore posts(contains only the image) in a grid layout and when we click on them, it changes to another feed like view showing more details.

The way I am thinking to implement is to have two fragments with recycler views: 1 for grid layout and 1 for feed like. Share the currently, loaded feed items between these two recycler view adapters.

**Question:** Is it the correct approach to share adapter items between two views? If not, what would the design be? I suspect I will run into issues if we share the items.

Kindly let me know if any more details is needed. I can share pictures as well in case someone needs for android device.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What do you mean by "share adapter items"? What are "adapter items"? Are you talking about the views or the data? What is a "feed like view"? You cannot assume that we have used the app that you are trying to recreate. It would help if you provide some mockups of the layouts you wish to create.

Comment: Adapter items are the individual data units that make up the content for recycler views in this case a photo and its metadata. Feed like view is something that we see on many social apps like Facebook, Instagram, etc where it shows an item with info like likes, comments, etc.

Comment: you want to share the current list of loaded feed, then one approach would be to put the list (like primary key and url to fetch the details from server) into a singelton.
In grid you have images. If same image can be reused, do no re query it. Use cached ones

Comment: So my first fragment need to show only the photo and when i click on a photo it should switch to a feed like view where along with the photo it shiws the metadata as well. This can be done for one item, but i need to do this for all the items in the adapter hence the thought of sharing the adapter items. I hope it is more clear. I will add some photos.

Comment: The data should be stored internally in some kind of model class, perhaps a simple POJO. You can send these objects between fragments by making them Parcelable.

Comment: thanks! Yeah I definitely did that :) Just wanted to check if it would cause any issues of sharing the list with two different adapters! It is working as expected for me.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and implemented my design. Till now, I haven't seen any issues.